# How do I create a character set like ASCII?

Tags: encoding, character, ascii, decode

I'm curious about the way that in the past it was implemented and I want to get information about how can I implement a character set of my own.

Comment: 1. Make an arbitrary table to your liking mapping bytes to characters. 2. Implement the necessary software to teach all relevant software your chosen mapping and make characters appear on screen. (Optional: 3. Get it approved by some standards body and/or included into other software so it's widely supported.)

Comment: First step—if you are going to document it electronically—is to choose a character set to use for your documentation file. ☺

Answer (score 1):

ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) was the "original" characterset, and remains the basis for most text data. ASCII is actually a 7-bit code (the numeric values range from 0 to 127) with the most significant bit of a byte indicating if the rest of the byte refers to ASCII (if zero) or the current Codepage.

Extra (non-ascii) characters were then added to these codepages, and the user's computer would load a specific codepage to use. Unfortunately this meant that you needed to load the correct codepage before viewing a file or the wrong characters would appear.

We have now moved on, and most systems use Unicode which is a variable character length (rather than the single-byte characters used previously) which can contain thousands upon thousands of characters, allowing for a single encoding to cater for what would have been multiple codepages using the ASCII+Codepage method of old.

That's the brief history; As to how to create your own characterset, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve - You can create your own fonts, but if you're talking about an actual characterset (i.e. characters that do not already exist) then you'll have to get your characterset added to a standard such as Unicode so that other computers can make use of your new characters, which would be a considerable amount of work (and I have no idea how you'd even go about it) -- It's worth considering, however, that almost every character in existence already exists in Unicode so you may want to review what's already been done before you try and take on a mammoth undertaking such as creating an entirely new characterset.

Comment: Good point, well made - I was trying to keep it as brief as possible rather than go into the entire history of character sets (hence "Original" not Original)!

Comment: Not all code pages are supersets of ASCII. The very popular—in the PC era—CP437 (IBM OEM) character set has graphic characters in place of most control characters. ☺☻♥ ♦ … ▲ ▼

Comment: They were still control characters though, that's just how they were interpreted if used as a literal character - a kind of hack to add on some extra funny characters. If you transfer a file of those files to another system (Atari ST, Amiga, Etc around that time) they'd display differently, and maybe more commonly they wouldn't print (hence the term non-printing character).